# Google Map API v3 - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, widget

I have been developing a `JS widget` for the last 5 or 6 weeks. The idea is that it can be added to any site by simply adding a href to the remote .js file and also a DIV container with a given ID to contain the contents of the widget.

The widget makes extensive use of Google Map API and I am referencing it as follows:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initializeGoogleMaps
```

When the widget is loaded, it will ask the user permission to check their location and then perform, amongst other operations, a simply geocoding for the location so that a marker can be plotted on the map.

Everything has been working perfectly and I must've tested the searching over 2,000 during development.

I deployed the widget yesterday and successfully embedded it into a host website - everything worked as perfectly as it always has done. This morning, however, my widget is falling over with **Chrome's console reporting:**

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded{main,geometry,places}.js:27 (anonymous function)VM530:33 cVM530:33 TT.(anonymous function).fitBounds{main,geometry,places}.js:48 (anonymous function){main,geometry,places}.js:26 Uf{main,geometry,places}.js:48 O.fitBoundsWRAPPostcodeLocator.js:1541 setupPageWRAPPostcodeLocator.js:964 jQuery.ajax.successjquery.js?time=95944:3 jjquery.js?time=95944:3 k.fireWithjquery.js?time=95944:12 xjquery.js?time=95944:12 b.onload.b.onreadystatechange
```

Since the widget last worked, no changes have been made to my code or the host, so I suspect something wrong with the Google API.

An example of my widget embedded into a dummy host can be seen at:

```
http://pcl.solsticecloud.co.uk
```

Having spent several hours trying to get to the bottom of this, I'm still non the wiser.

Any help or advice would be so much appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Matt

Comment: Don't use the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) in production, it can break at any time.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Matt Alexander this was exactly the problem and the solution, however it seems that Google changed the names of the Location properties AGAIN, not **.k** and **.D** anymore, now its **.A** and **.F**!, take a look at the following console log:

[image: Console Log]

Comment: Undocumented properties are undocumented for a reason: they are not part of the public API and could change at any time. The correct way to access the latitude and longitude of a `LatLng`  object is by calling the `lat()` and `lng()` methods as documented in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng).

Comment: I think google is intentionally keeping us developers on our toes. I ran into this issue but my code differers a bit more since the time of this post. From .G and .K to .H and .L  (I believe those are coming from markers positions.

Comment: @Yaniv the geocoder.geocode function doesn't return a `LatLng` object. So you can't call `lat()` or `lng()` on the returned response.

Comment: @inorganik GeocoderResult.geometry.location is a LatLng object.

Answer (score 2):

For nowadays it's '.G' and '.K'. And as said - it's better to use '.lat()' and '.lng()'.

Comment: This is odd, you answered this on September 1st, and it seems now on the 15th with the latest copy of google maps api, this .G and .K has changed to .H and .L. Though I am up voting this, as this should be the answer. lat() and lng() are the way to go if you don't want to maintain the code in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
 keys = Object.keys(LatLng);
 geometry.location[keys[0]]; // Obtain value for latitude
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Beware that older browsers don't support this ES5 feature.

Comment: Google's Map API has changed. The results are no longer properties, but methods, lat() and lng() respectively. They can be called to obtain the proper values instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of this issue and have a fix.

I was using the following code:

```
        address = document.getElementById("strSearch").value;

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, componentRestrictions: { country: 'GB' } }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            toggleModal();

            deleteMarkers();
            deleteBanks();

            searchSourceLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.k, results[0].geometry.location.B);
            setSearchPointPostcode(results, buildResults);
        }

        else {
            callback();
        }
    })
```

The particular line that caused the issue is:

```
searchSourceLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.k, results[0].geometry.location.B);
```

".B" has worked for weeks, but now it would seem that is no longer a valid property. Instead, ".D" works and so my code now works.

As the property was no longer valid, I had a LatLng object with a null value and this caused the map to crash when I tried to see my map boundaries.

I would love to know how or why this has changed in the API.

Also, a stupid question I'm sure, but why ".k" and ".D"? What's wrong with ".Lng" and ".Lat"?

Glad it's sorted though, just hope the API doesn't change again.

Comment: The correct way to access the latitude and longitude of a `LatLng`  object is by calling the `lat()` and `lng()` methods as documented in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng). Values like `.k` and `.D` are automatically generated by the Closure Compiler and can (and, as you've observed, do!) change at any time. Only documented object properties should be used if you wish your implementation to be reliable.

Comment: I second that comment. Any one-letter variable names are automatically generated during an optimization phase and are never intended to be called directly. Read the docs on how to use these objects properly, and you'll see that there are legitimate public methods to access

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the properties of `location` and get the coordinates without accessing its properties directly:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': value.address }, function (results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {

    var coords = [];
    for (var key in results[0].geometry.location) {
        coords.push(results[0].geometry.location[key]);
    }
    return {
        'latitude': coords[0],
        'longitude': coords[1]
    };
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this one hope it will help you

```
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mappnl.el.dom, {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: {
                        lat: 52.132633,
                        lng: 5.291265999999999
                    },
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                });
                var latlong = [];
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();        
                if(frmvalue.dir_postalcode_standard){
                    geocoder.geocode({
                        'address': frmvalue.dir_postalcode_standard
                    }, function(results, status) {

                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                            slat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            slng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                            latlong['standard'] = {
                                'lat': slat,
                                'lng': slng
                            };
                            var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                                strokeColor: '#00FF00',
                                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                strokeWeight: 1,
                                fillColor: '#00FF00',
                                fillOpacity: 0.15,
                                map: map,
                                center: {
                                    lat: slat,
                                    lng: slng
                                },
                                radius: frmvalue.dir_radius_standaard * 1000
                            });
                            map.setCenter({
                                lat: slat,
                                lng: slng
                            });

                            geocoder.geocode({
                                'address': frmvalue.dir_postalcode_extended
                            }, function(results, status) {

                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                                    elat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                    elng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                                    latlong['extended'] = {
                                        'lat': elat,
                                        'lng': elng
                                    };

                                    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
                                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                        strokeWeight: 1,
                                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                                        fillOpacity: 0.15,
                                        map: map,
                                        center: {
                                            lat: elat,
                                            lng: elng
                                        },
                                        radius: frmvalue.dir_radius_extended * 1000
                                    });
                                    callback(latlong);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this file has the problem : **https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js**

So if you use mine it definitely works.

Instead of using this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Use this one:

> google-chart-loader.js

```
<script src="~/Content/js/google-chart-loader.js"></script>
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eOPtgJ9FoZ6917q3OcNPKGe3AT-PXIzg