# Google Map Geocode succeeds but Latitude is not found

Tags: javascript, google-maps, visual-studio-2013

This is my exception:

[image]
When I hit break and hover over the value `c` it is `OK` and value B has values:

[image]

Here is al my javascript:

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            //console.log(results);
            //console.log("Lat: " + results[0].geometry.location.coords.latitude);
            //console.log("Lng: " + results[0].geometry.location.coords.longitude);
            return results[0].geometry.location;
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

So there is a `results` and it is filled, but it is no lat long.
The address I used for testing is: **1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA** based on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests but this is not just for this address.

I have seriously no idea. It is almost an exact copy of the sample code.

**edit** jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7tvv71hs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lat() and lng() are functions and not properties.
just call them.

Refer:

1. [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)
2. [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420052/google-map-api-v3-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded/32336242#32336242)